# Calculating multiple inputs value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm having trouble going trough making a calculator (sum only) of 5 inputs fields in html/javascript and i can't manage to find what's wrong in my code

i tried messing around with types such as int instead of var and passing the value into parseInt, i somehow managed to have a result like "11111" where it should be like "5" but alongside that case the result is never printed in the innerHTML even after i added the "if not null" condition

Here is my html

```html
    <body>
        <h1 class="head-title"></h1>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="design">Design :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="design">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="plot">Plot :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="plot">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="character">Character :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="character">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="enjoyment">Enjoyment :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="enjoyment">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="music">Music :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="music">
        </div>
        <div class="button-group">
            <button class="button-primary" onclick="ratingCompute();">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="total">Rating :</label>
            <p class="rating-score" id="total"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and here is my javascript

```js
function ratingCompute()
{
    var designValue = document.getElementById("design").value;
    var plotValue = document.getElementById("plot").value;
    var charValue = document.getElementById("character").value;
    var enjoyValue = document.getElementById("enjoyment").value;
    var musicValue = document.getElementById("music").value;
    var totalValue = designValue + plotValue + charValue + enjoyValue + musicValue;

    if (totalValue != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalValue + "/10";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "0/10";
    }
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: Try parsing values to an integer with `parseInt(stringValue, 10)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Joshua Aclan, JavaScript does not have an "int" variable declaration, only "var". Also you have to cast all of the inputs to int or float, because otherwise you are adding strings and the values of input fields are always strings. Also the output is most likely empty because `int designValue...` produces an error.

```
function ratingCompute()
{
    var designValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("design").value);
    var plotValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("plot").value);
    var charValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").value);
    var enjoyValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("enjoyment").value);
    var musicValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("music").value);
    var totalValue = designValue + plotValue + charValue + enjoyValue + musicValue;

    if (totalValue != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalValue + "/10";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "0/10";
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks for the answer you're true, i just messed up with the paste when posting the question, actually i use vars but still i have something like 11111 in the output when doing so

Comment: My example also has `parseInt` added to all input values. This is mandatory if you want to work with numbers instead of strings.

Comment: Right, didn't knew exactly how to use parseInt so i must haved messed up when trying it out by myself i was trying something like adding parseInt at the end of the statement, very useful answer thank you

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is not a type variable language try using let or const. And here is how you properly parse it. If you did it already then its because of your variable declaration.

```
let designValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("design").value);
let plotValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("plot").value);
let charValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").value);
let enjoyValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("enjoyment").value);
let musicValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("music").value);
```

Comment: The lesson: Always. Check. The. Console.

Comment: you're right, i just copy-pasted the wrong instance of my script i actually use vars sorry

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you should use keyword **var/let/const** instead of int. and you have to convert String type input value to int using **parseInt** method.

Please check this:

```js
function ratingCompute()
{
    var designValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("design").value);
    var plotValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("plot").value);
    var charValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").value);
    var enjoyValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("enjoyment").value);
    var musicValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("music").value);
    var totalValue = designValue + plotValue + charValue + enjoyValue + musicValue;

    if (totalValue)
    {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalValue + "/10";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "0/10";
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
        <h1 class="head-title"></h1>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="design">Design :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="design">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="plot">Plot :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="plot">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="character">Character :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="character">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="enjoyment">Enjoyment :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="enjoyment">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="music">Music :</label>
            <input class="input-text" type="number" id="music">
        </div>
        <div class="button-group">
            <button class="button-primary" onclick="ratingCompute()">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="total">Rating :</label>
            <p class="rating-score" id="total"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
```